# Inserção de dados, converter Int para String

Tags: java

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

O erro acontece pq na classe Funcionario_DAO(), as variaveis com erro estão declaradas como INT, eu não me lembro qual código para conversão correto.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

O a conversão pode ser feita conforme abaixo:

```
 Integer.valueOf(Txt_Email.getText())
```

Caso o valor seja do tipo primitivo voce pode fazer:

```
  Integer.valueOf(Txt_Email.getText()).intValue()
```

No seu caso ficaria:

```
objFunc_Enc.setEmail(Integer.valueOf(Txt_Email.getText()).intValue())
```

Uma sugestão em Java utiliza-se alguns padrões para identificadores(nome de classes, atributos, e métodos), para os nomes de variáveis e atributos utiliza-se letras em no padrão camelcase sendo a letra inicial minúscula.

Comment: Marciano, ainda estou começando em java, eu entendi a teoria, mas pode me mostrar como ficaria a sintaxe completa? obrigado pela atenção.

Comment: Olá Gustavo, o que você não entendeu?

Comment: Por exemplo:
objFunc_Enc.setEmail(Txt_Email.getText());
onde tenho que inserir: Integer.valueOf(Txt_Email.getText())?

Pensei numa sintaxe mais ou menos assim:
objFunc_Enc.setEmail.Integer.valueOf(Txt_Email.getText());
mas deu erro, entao acho que estou equivocado.

Comment: Atualizei a resposta, verifique por favor.

Comment: deu certo, ficou: objFunc_Enc.setEmail(Integer.parseInt(Txt_Email.getText()));

OBRIGADO!!!